# How to conditional INSERT INTO from different tables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, insert-into

I am writing a stored procedure to do some common checks, in the stored procedure I have code like the following to avoid creating too many `@variables`:

```
IF type = 'spl' 
THEN BEGIN
    SELECT col1, col4, col5, col9, col20, ... INTO #tmp
    FROM tbl1 
    WHERE primary_key = unique_id
END
ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT col1, col5, col7, col8, col19, ... INTO #tmp
    FROM tbl2
    WHERE primary_key = unique_id
END
```

Though these two `INSERT` could never run at the same time, it still causes a `#tmp table already exist` error, and the stored procedure can't be created.

Is there any common work around for this?

The following is certainly possible, but it looks worse then declaring dozens of `@variables`. But it is the only thing I can come up with atm.

```
SELECT * 
INTO #TEMP 
FROM 
     (SELECT 
          CASE WHEN type = 'spl' 
                  THEN a.col1 
                  ELSE b.col1 
               END, 
   ...
   FROM ... CROSS JOIN ... 
)
```

Comment: If both select statements return the same number of columns with the same data types in the same order, you can first create the temp table (using `create table #temp) and then `insert...select` instead of `select...into`. If not, you can use two different tables. It's hard to give a good answer without some more context.

Comment: This is very likely to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). So be careful about choosing a path. Why? What columns are created in your temp table? If you are not careful, you will get a table that contains columns whose names vary due to your logic. You will then find it difficult to use this table. Zohar touched on this indirectly. We, of course, **hope** that your "col1", "col4", etc. are obfuscated column names. But I've seen that in real life and it is not a good sign.

Comment: You could use `insert into ... select ... from tbl1 where @type = 'spl' and primary_key = unique_id union all select ... from tbl2 where @type <> 'spl' and primary_key = unique_id`, but executing separate queries should be clearer and more efficient. Tip: You can create an empty temporary table using `select .. into #tmp where 42 = 6 * 9;`. The impossible condition will prevent rows from being added.

Comment: Thanks, folks. So many good points. I got your answers. To avoid tedious column type declarations; I should `SELECT col1 alias1, col3 alias1, colM aliasN into #temp from table1 where 1=2` which will create the empty table for me, then `INSERT INTO` conditionally. If anyone could write answer, I will upvote them.

Comment: I think that @HABO have suggested the best solution in the comments, so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a "conditional" insert from multiple data sources by combining them with `union all` and having individual `where` clauses that will cause only one data source to produce rows:

```
insert into #tmp
  select col1, col2, ...
    from tbl1
    where @type = 'spl' and primary_key = unique_id
  union all
  select col1, col2, ...
    from tbl2
    where @type <> 'spl' and primary_key = unique_id;
```

If you want to have the output table created for you, you can use `select ... into ...` with a `where` clause that prevents any rows from being inserted. The result will be an empty table with the correct schema:

```
-- Create empty   #tmp   table.
select col1, col2, ...
  from tbl1
  into #tmp
  where 42 = 6 * 9; -- Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything.
```

Note that executing separate queries using `if`/`then` allows the query optimizer to generate optimal plans for *each* query rather than the whole `union all` mash up, and it makes the intent clearer for long term maintenance.

It may also be a good time to read up on [parameter sniffing](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/).